# what does the "~" operator do in java as in: byte b =~5 + 1

Tags: java

What does the "~" operator do in java as in: `byte b =~5 + 1` ?

When the result is sent to standard out `System.out.print(b)` it prints `'-5'` but I don't know why or what it represents.

Comment: If only there were a list of Java operators somewhere.

Comment: If only there were a [list of Java operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) somewhere. ;)

Answer (score 6):

It's the bitwise complement operator.  Since java uses [two's complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) to represent negative numbers, `~x + 1` is equivalent to `-x`.

Comment: No, I don't mean `-x - 1`.  Where did that come from?

Comment: oh my bad I didn't see you wrote ~x + 1

Comment: Thanks for your help. But why does ~5 + 1 = -5 and not -4?

Comment: read up on 2's complement and you will understand